# HEX to RGB using an iterator - better way than using .forEach?

Tags: javascript

I've created a rather ugly function for converting hex to rgb and I really don't like the way I've used `.forEach` and the need for defining an empty array before the iteration.

I feel like there should be a better way for doing things like this that I'm not aware of?
I've tried `.reduce`, `map` and a few others but I need to return a new array and push to it every other character.

```
const rgba = (hex, alpha) => {
  const pairs = [...hex.slice(1, hex.length)];
  const rgb = [];
  pairs.forEach((char, index) => {
    if (index % 2 !== 0) return;
    const pair = `${char}${pairs[index + 1]}`;
    rgb.push(parseInt(pair, 16));
  });

  return `rgba(${rgb.join(', ')}, ${alpha})`;
};
```

Comment: The question isn't specific to ES6. And it is solved with reduce. What exactly did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do as follows;

```js
function hex2rgb(h){
  return "rgb(" + [(h & 0xff0000) >> 16, (h & 0x00ff00) >> 8, h & 0x0000ff].reduce((p,c) => p+","+c) + ")";
}

console.log(hex2rgb(0xffffff));
console.log(hex2rgb(0x12abf0));
console.log(hex2rgb(0x000000));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler solution without any loops at all:

```
const rgba = (hex, alpha) => {
    let clr = parseInt(hex.slice(1), 16),
        rgb = [
            (clr >> 16) & 0xFF,
            (clr >>  8) & 0xFF,
            (clr >>  0) & 0xFF
        ];
  return `rgba(${rgb.join(', ')}, ${alpha})`;
};
```

If your question is more about how to organize a 'pairwise' loop, you can use a function similar to [python's `itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
let groupBy = function*(iter, fn) {
    let group = null,
        n = 0,
        last = {};

    for (let x of iter) {
        let key = fn(x, n++);

        if (key === last) {
            group.push(x);
        } else {
            if (group)
                yield group;
            group = [x];
        }

        last = key;
    }

    yield group;
};
```

Once this is done, the rest is trivial:

```
const rgba = (hex, alpha) => {
    let pairs = [...groupBy(hex.slice(1), (_, n) => n >> 1)]
    let rgb = pairs.map(x => parseInt(x.join(''), 16));
    return `rgba(${rgb.join(', ')}, ${alpha})`;
};
```